# Angular - Route ID is not populating

Tags: angular, angular-routing

When someone submits a form, it transfers them to a new page and the url would be - 4200/id
Currently, the ID is "". and is not populating. I recently added "PrimeNG" I doubt that has anything to do with it though.
How do I fix this? thank you so much to anyone that answers, I've been stuck on this problem all day.

```
{ // Routing Module
path: ':id',
loadChildren: () =>
  import('./features/project-details/project-details.module').then(
    (m) => m.ProjectDetailsModule
  ),
```

},

```
// The form button that submits the data.
<button
  type="submit"
  class="btn btn-primary"
  [disabled]="form.invalid"
  [routerLink]="['', newProject.id]"
  routerLinkActive="router-link-active"
>
  Submit
</button>

// The Submit() Method.
this.newProject.projectName = this.form.get('name').value;
this.newProject.projectDescription = this.form.get('description').value;
this.newProject.interests = this.categoriesFormArraySelectedIds;
const uid = this.afsc.createId();
this.newProject.id = uid;
this.firestoreService.createProject(this.newProject, uid);


// Details Page (The page that gets the data from the ID that you send.)
ngOnInit() {
this.route.paramMap.subscribe((data) => {
  this.routeName = data.get('id');
});

this.firestore
  .collection('Projects', (query) =>
    query.where('id', '==', this.routeName)
  )
  .get()
  .subscribe((data) => {
    data.forEach((doc) => {
      // tslint:disable-next-line: no-shadowed-variable
      const data = doc.data();
      this.projectName = data.projectName;
      this.projectDescription = data.projectDescription;
      this.interests = data.interests;
      this.id = data.id;
      this.interests.join('+');
    });
  });
```

}

[image]

Comment: have you checked that `this.newProject.id` has value before submitting?

Comment: @kushalshah Yes it does.

Comment: here i have create similar example please look into and see what you are missing.. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-route-parameters-pes6bg?file=app%2Fapp.component.html